# Node.js and Grunt install on Windows

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I have Node.js installed and I have ran `npm install -g grunt-cli` I have `cd` to the directory of the app I am to work on and followed the instructions [here](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started#working-with-an-existing-grunt-project). When I run `grunt` in my cmd it returns

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^

Error: Cannot find module '\\Server\username$\Redirected\AppData\npm\AppData\npm\node_modules\grunt-cli'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3
```

I really am not sure why its trying to read from `\AppData\npm\AppData\npm\` as I haven't made any changes and I don't know how to change the grunt location

But when I use `npm install -g grunt-cli` it downloads and installs to the following `\\Server\username$\Redirected\AppData\npm\node_modules\grunt-cli`

Comment: It looks like maybe it is getting confused on the UNC path for your profile. NPM packages are installed in your local %USERPROFILE%\AppData\npm

Comment: @nschonni how can I change it to leave the UNC path and goto say `C:\\Users\username` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the global install directory.

Try this ..

In C:\Users{username}\, create .npmrc file with contents:

```
prefix = "C:\\Users\\{username}\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm"
```

This is discussed more fully here:

[Change default global installation directory for node.js modules in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874582/change-default-global-installation-directory-for-node-js-modules-in-windows)