# Change default global installation directory for node.js modules in Windows?

Tags: node.js, npm

In my windows installation `PATH` includes `C:\Program Files\nodejs`, where executable `node.exe` is. I'm able to launch `node` from the shell, as well as `npm`. I'd like new executables to be installed in `C:\Program Files\nodejs` as well, but it seems impossible to achieve.

Setting `NODE_PATH` and `NODE_MODULES` variables doesn't change anything: things are still installed in `%appdata%\npm` by default.

How can I change the global installation path?

Comment: Probably because gremo wants to have all nodejs related dependencies in one place. Problem is, that with updating nodejs you'd lose all installed packages. On the other hand putting npm in the user's %appdata% folder makes it inaccessible to other user's on the same machine. Think of installing it as normal user vs administrator.

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685892/how-do-i-fix-npms-global-location

Comment: Moving out of %AppData% to a more _controlled location_ makes a lot of sense to me, since it feels quite %temp%-ish to mee. (Doing the same for Firefox profiles and a few others). However `C:\Program Files` is poised for constant admin right troubles. ➪ I'd rather move do `D:\my-repository\npm` or such.

Comment: @WiredPrairie because install in user folders is pretty much just stupid. The whole point of 'globally' installing packages is that a system as a whole can access these packages.

Comment: You can't add %AppData% to the user %PATH%, which makes grunt-cli really annoying to install on windows by default

Comment: Here's a reason to do this: on my network you are not allowed to execute code out of the AppData folder because that's often how malware, especially CodeLocker, gets downloaded and run. It's an extra layer of protection against malware. Since Node installs things there I can't run node modules without moving the install location or decreasing security on my system.

Comment: Reasons why: #1 Path names can't be too long on Windows.  #2 I'd like to be able to easily maintain my global packages.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Everything you need is in the [`npm-folders` documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders). I don't want to start my Win notebook now so I cannot verify it, but you should only change `prefix` to `C:\Program Files\nodejs` in your config file. If you want to change it globally for all users, edit the `C:\Program Files\nodejs\npmrc` file, otherwise create/edit `C:\Users\{username}\.npmrc`.

**But this change will probably have some side effects, so read [this discussion](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/2207) first. I don't think it's a good idea.**

Comment: I found the `npmrc` file at `C:\path\to\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc`

Comment: also change the npm cache location to a local directory using `npm config set cache <new cache location> --global` if you run into problems while installing modules and cache is in a shared drive.

I got this error, `ENOENT: no such file or directory` when the cache was in a shared drive

Comment: Don't forget to update the system PATH variable to point to the new npm folder.

Answer (score 84):

trying to install *global* packages into `C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\` gave me **Run as Administrator** issues, because npm was trying to install into
`C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\`

to resolve this, change *global* install directory to `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\npm`:

in `C:\Users\{username}\`, create `.npmrc` file with contents:

`prefix = "C:\\Users\\{username}\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm"`

*reference*

- `npm install -g package` [installs *global* packages into *prefix* location](https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/v1.4.10/doc/files/npm-folders.md#prefix-configuration)
- [npmrc userconfig takes priority and overrides](https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/v1.4.10/doc/files/npmrc.md#files)
- `npm config ls -l` was showing `prefix = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs"`

*environment*
nodejs x86 installer into `C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\` on Windows 7 Ultimate N 64-bit SP1
`node --version` : v0.10.28
`npm --version` : 1.4.10

Comment: This is strange I was using npm 2.1.6, and it was installing all global modules in %appdata%/npm, now that I updated it to 2.6.1, it keeps trying (and failing) to install to c:\windows\program files\.. Do you happen to know when this behaviour changed?

Comment: here's some [node wiki diffs](https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting/_compare/fada1f67eab96cc9e320635bd1c7ab6c5fd26920...78b0a824fd358947748939268eac269823b69577?short_path=44dd9b8#diff-44dd9b836298bf616cf57a21c9e319ad)

Comment: it seems it was to do with a different way I installed npm. Thanks for the diff though.

Comment: npm config set prefix C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\npm

Comment: @WORMSS I got this issue after upgrading from Node 12 to Node 14, using the same installation method though (msi installer, 64 bits). Never had it before, funny how old issues from pre-v1 can resurface...

Comment: This saved my life! The `prefix` value was pointing to a different folder. Because of this, no matter how many times I install/uninstall angular cli globally, I would get this error: `'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command`.  Changing the value of the prefix variable in the `.npmrc` file to `prefix=C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm` where `admin` is my username, fixed the issue. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 71):

You can see my answer to this in my [answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9366416/43906).

---

In Windows, the *global* install path is actually in your user's profile directory

- `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm`
- `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache`
- WARNING: If you're doing timed events or other automation as a different user, make sure you run `npm install` as that user. Some modules/utilities should be installed globally.
- INSTALLER BUGS: You may have to create these directories or add the `...\npm` directory to your users path yourself.

---

To change the "global" location for all users to a more appropriate shared global location `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\(npm|npm-cache)` (do this as an administrator):

- create an `[NODE_INSTALL_PATH]\etc\` directory

  - this is needed before you try `npm config --global ...` actions
- create the global (admin) location(s) for npm modules

  - `C:\ProgramData\npm-cache` - npm modules will go here
  - `C:\ProgramData\npm` - binary scripts for globally installed modules will go here
  - `C:\ProgramData\npm\node_modules` - globally installed modules will go here
  - set the permissions appropriately

    - administrators: modify
    - authenticated users: read/execute
- Set global configuration settings (Administrator Command Prompt)

  - `npm config --global set prefix "C:\ProgramData\npm"`
  - `npm config --global set cache "C:\ProgramData\npm-cache"`
- Add `C:\ProgramData\npm` to your System's Path environment variable

---

If you want to change your user's "global" location to `%LOCALAPPDATA%\(npm|npm-cache)` path instead:

- Create the necessary directories

  - `C:\Users\YOURNAME\AppData\Local\npm-cache` - npm modules will go here
  - `C:\Users\YOURNAME\AppData\Local\npm` - binary scripts for installed modules will go here
  - `C:\Users\YOURNAME\AppData\Local\npm\node_modules` - globally installed modules will go here
- Configure npm

  - `npm config set prefix "C:\Users\YOURNAME\AppData\Local\npm"`
  - `npm config set cache "C:\Users\YOURNAME\AppData\Local\npm-cache"`
- Add the new npm path to your environment's `PATH`.

  - `setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Users\YOURNAME\AppData\Local\npm"`

Comment: Setting the global location to C:\ProgramData as per your middle suggestion seems to be the best place for this in a windows environment, but I don't see how you can set the prefix in the global config file when the prefix is used to find the global config file. I achieved the same result by editing the builtin config file C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc but I suspect this change may get overwritten by an update at some stage.

Comment: @oenpelli In this case "global" is your user's `.npmrc` file in the home/profile directory.  It would need to be set for all users.

Comment: If I have no admin permission on windows, how can I change the global installation?

Comment: liam, you can adjust this for your user via an `.npmrc` file in your profile directory... though, ymmv at that point.

Answer (score 22):

Building on the installation concept of `chocolatey` and the idea suggested by @Tracker, what worked for me was to do the following and all users on windows were then happy working with `nodejs` and `npm`.

Choose `C:\ProgramData\nodejs` as installation directory for `nodejs` and install `nodejs` with any user that is a member of the administrator group.

This can be done with chocolatey as: `choco install nodejs.install -ia "'INSTALLDIR=C:\ProgramData\nodejs'"`

Then create a folder called `npm-cache` at the root of the installation directory, which after following above would be `C:\ProgramData\nodejs\npm-cache`.

Create a folder called `etc` at the root of the installation directory, which after following above would be `C:\ProgramData\nodejs\etc`.

Set `NODE` environment variable as `C:\ProgramData\nodejs`.

Set `NODE_PATH` environment variable as  `C:\ProgramData\nodejs\node_modules`.

Ensure `%NODE%` environment variable previously created above is added (or its path) is added to `%PATH%` environment variable.

Edit `%NODE_PATH%\npm\npmrc` with the following content `prefix=C:\ProgramData\nodejs`

From command prompt, set the global config like so...

`npm config --global set prefix "C:\ProgramData\nodejs"`

`npm config --global set cache "C:\ProgramData\nodejs\npm-cache"`

It is important the steps above are carried out preferably in sequence and before updating npm (`npm -g install npm@latest`) or attempting to install any `npm` module.

Performing the above steps helped us running `nodejs` as system wide installation, easily available to all users with proper permissions. Each user can then run `node` and `npm` as required.

Comment: what is the output of 'npm config list'.  Also, are you running on Windows or Linux?

Comment: Tried it on both. `npm config add prefix` works, but none of the environment variables mentioned here. I didn't want to open up another question because this question covers it, but the answers don't (besides `npm config`).

Comment: The NODE environment variable is essentially just to expose the binaries. You still need to set the prefix and cache (if not previously set) as mentioned in the procedure.

Comment: Oh, thank you. That was not very clear from the answers or anywhere else on Google. I was looking for environment variables as those are easier to change programmatically, but one-liner Bash commands are OK too, I suppose.

Comment: This worked beautifully for me. Thank you for the detailed instructions!

Comment: Anyone know what the etc folder is needed for?

Comment: @Dan The `etc` folder is where your `.npmrc` settings would be stored.

Comment: Also i would like to Add.  if you experience issue with `node-gyp` installing it's headers files in undesired directory for example by defaylt it's `UserDir/.node-gyp`  in case it contains non asci chars in username for example it will not build a lib for you. To solve it just add `npm_config_devdir` environment variable in with desired path  for example `C:\ProgramData\nodejs\.node-gyp`  also create this directory before setting environment variable and installation of node headers via `node-gyp install node@9.6.1` for example

Comment: in windows system program data, user folder folders are places you don't want to touch, their location has been changed at least 3 times during history of windows and each time broke a few application. A better location would be another drive which most probably is in a separate M2 key or SSD than your OS drive. In a windows server it is easier to configure security of a single folder than multiple locations including program data or user folder

Answer (score 21):

- **Step 1**:

  > npm config get prefix
  >
  > - Default Path is : `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm`
- **Step 2**:

  > npm config get cache
  >
  > - Default Path is : `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache`
- **Step 3**:

  > npm config set prefix \npm
  >
  > - example `npm config set prefix C:\\dev\\node\\npm`
- **Step 4**:

  > npm config set cache \npm-cache
  >
  > - example `npm config set cache C:\\dev\\node\\npm-cache`

Run steps 1 & 2 again to check whether the paths are updated as required

That's it. Whenever you install global packages you should see them installed inside \npm\node_modules

Comment: Thanks your solution solved my issue, from last 2 weeks I was trying to solve the issue, Actually my windows user path had spaces in it like ABC XYZ WJS so then I changed the path to just one word, after that My npm install was giving errors, so your solution help me to clear the cache and set cache to my new location.

Answer (score 16):

You should use this command to set the global installation flocation of npm packages

**(git bash)** `npm config --global set prefix </path/you/want/to/use>/npm`

**(cmd/git-cmd)** `npm config --global set prefix <drive:\path\you\want\to\use>\npm`

You may also consider the `npm-cache` location right next to it. (as would be in a normal nodejs installation on windows)

**(git bash)** `npm config --global set cache </path/you/want/to/use>/npm-cache`

**(cmd/git-cmd)** `npm config --global set cache <drive:\path\you\want\to\use>\npm-cache`

Comment: Glad to help. It would also be a great idea to make a shel script or batch file to execute this up for you whenever you change your environment. At least that's what id do

Comment: Also worth adding " if there are spaces in the path. e.g. `"C:\Program Files\blah"`.

Answer (score 4):

The default global folder is `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\npm`.
You can create (if it doesn't exist) a `.npmrc` file in `C:\Users\{username}\` and add 
`prefix = "path\\to\\yourglobalfolder"`.
Note that, in windows, the path should be separated by `double back-slash`.

Answer (score 4):

Using a Windows symbolic link from the *C:\Users{username}\AppData\Roaming\npm* and *C:\Users{username}\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache* paths to the destination worked great for me.

[How to add a symbolic link](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-symlinks-in-windows-vista/)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Find the current path of your global node package installation by following command.

npm list -g --depth=0

Change this path to correct path by following command.

npm set prefix C:\Users\username(Number)\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules

It worked for me. Read my previous answer for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, if you want to move the npm or nodejs folder in disk C to another location, but it still makes sure node and npm works well, you can create symlink like this:
Open Command Prompt:

```
mklink /D "your_location_want_to_create_symlink" "location_of_node_npm_file"
```

Example:

```
mklink /D "C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\npm" "D:\Nodejs Data\npm"
```

Now you've created a symlink for npm folder, this symlink will refer to `D:\Nodejs Data\npm`Everything will work well.

Answer (score 0):

I tried most of the answers here nothing seems to work in my case. So i changed the Temp location in my env variables to C:\npm. Then it started to work. This is not a good idea but a temporary solution.

Answer (score 0):

Delete node folder completely from program file folder. Uninstall node.js and then reinstall it.
change Path of environment variable PATH. delete .npmrc file from C:\users\yourusername

Comment: Have you any documentation or sources that support your statement? As written in it's current state, it's hard to tell if your suggestion actually works without trying it by yourself, which takes up time that could be saved otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

it does not require much configurations just go to advanced system settings copy the path where you have installed your node and just create an environment variable and check with node -v command in your prompt!

Answer (score 0):

To Change the default global installation directory for node.js(npm) modules in Windows, You need to fix 2 paths.

First check the current path where node modules are installing, when you try to install them globally by using following command :

npm list -g --depth=0

It will return you the current path where node modules are installing right now.
Example: D:\vsc\typescript

Now visit the following path to see npm and npm-cache folder.
C:\Users\username(OR Number)\AppData\Roaming

In Roaming folder of your C drive you will find npm and npm-cache folder.
Click on the + npm + folder and select the path[Just click on the bar path will be selected automatically, copy it ].[This is a path image which you need to select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHAKG.png)

Once you copy this path set this to the environment variables, with a variable name Path(anything you can select as a name).
Now you have set the path for your npm folder, now this is the time to set prefix.
Go inside npm folder and check if node_module folder exist, if not create a new folder named as node_modules.
You all global modules will come in this folder after completing all steps.

Final Step:
Go to CMD and right the following command:

npm set prefix C:\Users\username(Number)\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules

Again this is the same path we selected for environment variable, we are just adding one more folder in the path and that is node_module.

All Set....Try Now...It will work..