# npm install -g angular-cli doesnt work

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular2-cli

**Update:**

Okay It seccussfully installed "npm install -g angular-cli" but now I got new error: "You cannot use the new command inside an angular-cli project." while trying to do: "ng new ang2pro" for making a new project.

```
C:\Users\armyTik\Desktop\angular2_projects\1>ng new pro-name
(node:6512) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using
 the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
You cannot use the new command inside an angular-cli project.
```

---

**Original post:**

It was working just fine yestarday and now I get the following errors even after reinstalling nodejs:

(The cmd is open with administrator privileges)
[image: the cmd is open with administrator privileges]

Comment: is this error occurs only while installing `angular-cli` package or for all packages.  It clearly says there is some problem with your `global` directory path.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874582/change-default-global-installation-directory-for-node-js-modules-in-windows

Comment: The only steps I did is to create an empty folder and run inside 'npm install -g angular-cli'.

Comment: can you try instlalling other packages. like  `npm install -g jquery`

Comment: also  you don't have to go to empty directory to run this command. You can run it anywhere. It just installs the packages in the `global` path configured.  Default is `C:\<Username>AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\`

Comment: 'npm install -g jquery' installed! Anyways while installing npm install -g angular-cli , It says during installtion: "still install loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree". Is this the reason for the problem?

Comment: The `angular-cli` documentation talks about some `prerequisites :  Node 4 or greater, Typings V1 or greater` . Make sure you have these installed already.   https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#prerequisites

Comment: Okay It seccussfully installed "npm install -g angular-cli" but now I got new error: "You cannot use the new command inside an angular-cli project." while trying to do: "ng new ang2pro" for making a new project.

Comment: when did u get this error? after installing angular-cli ? or during?

Comment: after installinh -g angular-cli , I tryied to make new project by doing: "ng new project-name" and it failed with this error: "You cannot use the new command inside an angular-cli project.".

Comment: i think you need to run `ng new project-name` command from the root directory. Not inside the angular directory.

Comment: many thanks for your help but this problem has not been solved yet. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116708/discussion-between-venky-and-stav-alfi).

Comment: This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53817506/4657538)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on a mac don't forget sudo in front of the command

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `prerequisites` installed on your machine.

`angular-cli needs  Node 4 or above &  Typings V1 or greater`

`node -v`  should be greater than 4

`node typings -v` should be greater than 1

otherwise  install `typings` using `npm install typings -g`

Comment: I do have all this and still not I get the same error.