# npm install -g @angular/cli not working

Tags: javascript, angular, git-bash

Running the command `npm install -g @angular/cli` in `git bash` does not provide any feedback; it appears to be frozen!

**More Information**

If I run the following commands, I receive feedback:

```
$ npm -v
5.5.1

$ node -v
v8.9.3
```

However, running `npm install -g @angular/cli` shows nothing, nor a prompt for more input. It appears to be processing something, but does not show me the installation progress as it normally does.

Comment: Check another one by vpn.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47670693/not-able-to-install-angular-cli\

Comment: Wait for response, sometime it takes 2-5 minutes

Comment: this is normal if you are using git bash it takes some time so wait for it a couple of minutes and it will print the logs at the end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not to worry! This command is working as expected; however, the problem is that `git bash` does not show on-going messages regarding the installation progress of npm packages.

Give it a few minutes and you'll receive the confirmation that the package has been successfully installed.

**Suggestion**:

You may want to use **command prompt** or **terminal** for any further interaction with `npm`.

---

**Still having Issues?**

If you've given the command a few minutes to install and are still not having any luck, run these commands:

```
$ npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
$ npm cache verify
$ npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Wait a few minutes and you should be good to go!

Comment: It worked.I used ($ npm uninstall g @angular/cli) then,($ npm clear cache) and than ($ npm install g @angular/cli). Finally, wait for almost 2 mins and it installed successfully.

Comment: Great to hear! I've updated my answer to reflect your feedback. If you feel that my answer has solved your question, please mark it as the "Accepted Answers" so other users facing this issue can quickly refer to the correct answer.