# How to change npm globally installation path

Tags: node.js, npm

Is it possible to change where you install your dependencies when doing `npm install -g module`? I know it installed in your `C:/../{name}/Appdata..etc` but I want to change the path on mine due to limited disk space.

I've installed node.js on an external disk which is fine and can do npm commands, but now I want the global dependencies to be installed on this disk as well.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change default global installation directory for node.js modules in Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874582/change-default-global-installation-directory-for-node-js-modules-in-windows)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can configure it to new PATH by the following command -

```
npm config set prefix '~/.npm-new-global'
```

Comment: Thanks, I've installed angular-cli after this and its not giving the the command `ng`. Not sure if this is related to this.

Comment: Solved it now, I've added the angular-cli path in the environment path

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the environment variable `NPM_CONFIG_USERCONFIG` to set a new local for your config file, that is, `npmrc`. For instance, you can add to you login config file (`~/.profile`) the following line

```bash
export NPM_CONFIG_USERCONFIG="$HOME/.config/npm/npmrc"
```

Then, on the file `~/.config/npm/npmrc` you can write

```
cache=~/.cache/npm
prefix=$~/.local/share/npm
```

Here, the advantage is that you have set both the `~/.npm` and its cache to match with the [XDG Base Directory Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html)

[reference](https://bertptrs.nl/2017/03/06/cleaning-up-the-home-dir.html)