# Install npm windows-build-tools for all users and not just the administrative user

Tags: npm

I have installed windows-build-tools on my Windows 10 PC via following command:

```
npm install -g --production windows-build-tools
```

Since it requires administrative rights, I had to start the console as administrator. However, now, the Python and Visual C++ files installed with windows-build-tools are all saved on the user path of the administative user, and they are not available to all the other users on the same PC.

How can I make the files installed with windows-build-tools accessible to all users?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874582/change-default-global-installation-directory-for-node-js-modules-in-windows and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41181400/how-to-change-npm-globally-installation-path

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change default global installation directory for node.js modules in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874582/change-default-global-installation-directory-for-node-js-modules-in-windows)

Comment: Yes to the first, although it is similarly unanswered, which is really helpful. The second seems completely unrelated