# how to install angular cli to custom location

Tags: node.js, npm

I've just started working with `Angular` and with `Angular-CLI` and I've seen that, according to the documentation, I need to install `$ npm install -g @angular/cli` with the -g (global) flag.

Once the package is installed, the default path to it in Angular CLI will be something like `C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli`.

Now i want to install Angular CLI to something like this path `D:\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli`.

I tried `D:\>npm install @angular/cli`

[image]

Is it possible? Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874582/change-default-global-installation-directory-for-node-js-modules-in-windows.

This is not an Angular problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `--prefix` options to change the installation directory.

So for in this case it will be:

Step 1 : create a folder angular_cli in D drive

Step 2 : run this command after navigating to d drive

```
npm install --prefix D:\angular_cli\ @angular/cli
```

As a pre requirements, `D:\angular_cli\` folder must be exist

And append this path to path environment variable

```
D:\angular_cli
```

Answer (score 5):

As per [npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders#more-information) you can use `--prefix` options to change the installation directory:

#### Step 1:

Create `D:\angular_cli\` folder if it does not exist

#### Step 2:

```
npm install --prefix D:\angular_cli\ @angular/cli
```

#### Step 3:

Append `D:\angular_cli\node_modules\.bin` to path environment variable

Comment: Thanks for your answer this helps as expected. Could you explain how to add this to  path? `ng -v` and `ng new` are not working as expected.

Comment: It, depend on your os version. If it win 8 or higher, that should help - `setx path "%path%;d:\directoryPath"`. And if an answer was helpful, can you submit it as a correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what are doing with just installing `angular-cli` some custom location but yes, it's possible you just need to remove `-g` flag from the command of installation like below.

**Step1:** Navigate to your desired location of installation.

```
c:\>cd D:\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli
```

**Step2:** Install the angular-cli

```
D:\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli> npm install @angular/cli
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: The `node_modules` folder created but `ng  new` not working.

Comment: you need to set the path in your envronment variable