# npm package (PeerJS) installed but not recognized in command line

Tags: node.js, npm, peerjs

I'm trying to use PeerJS in the command line after I've installed it using

```
npm i -g peerjs
```

and I can confirm it's installed globally as it shows when I run

```
npm list -g --depth 0
```

When I try to run **peerjs** in the command line, it throws a **CommandNotFoundException**.

I've tried adding these to my user PATH variable:

[image: PATH]

I've also tried uninstalling and reinstalling PeerJS, as well as running the NodeJS Command Line app which is meant to set up the environment.

Any help on getting this command working would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you restarted your command line after updating your PATH?

Comment: @cbr Yes I tried restarting the command line, as well as my PC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably meant to install the [`peer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/peer) package, which is the [PeerJS server](https://github.com/peers/peerjs-server). That is the one that provides the `peerjs` command. The `peerjs` package contains the API library.

Comment: Tried installing peer and restarting cmd and still not working. When I run npm list -g --depth 0, it now shows both peerjs and peer: +-- peer@0.6.1 `-- peerjs@1.3.1

Comment: @RyanS If you go to `C:\Program Files\nodejs`, do you see `peerjs`?

Comment: You can also just use `npx peer`.

Comment: I don't, no. This is what I see: https://prnt.sc/wlqji0
Will try npx now.

Comment: @RyanS Which path does `npm prefix -g` output?

Comment: It outputs "C:\Users\Ryan"

Comment: Then your global packages are installed to `C:\Users\Ryan` and that's the path you need to add to your PATH. If you have a space in your username, you might need to change your npm prefix location to `C:\Users\Ryan~1`, or just change it to AppData\Roaming which I think is the default for the latest node versions. More about changing the path [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26894197/996081).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227198/discussion-between-ryan-s-and-cbr).

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to install [peerjs-server](https://github.com/peers/peerjs-server)

```sh
npm install peer -g
```

then close the cmd and reopen and then use it in commandline

```sh
peerjs --port 9000 --key peerjs --path /myapp
```

Comment: Tried installing peer and restarting cmd and still not working. When I run npm list -g --depth 0, it now shows both peerjs and peer:
+-- peer@0.6.1
`-- peerjs@1.3.1