# Why can't I install the angular cli? npm install -g @angular/cli does not install

Tags: node.js, npm, virtual-machine, angular-cli, vmware

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02GKz.png)

I am using a WMware virtual machine and when I tried to install CLI, I can not achieve that.
I tried to uninstall, npmcache, reinstall node.js, and more.

But I saw the same situation.

Comment: I have added the screnshoot

Comment: From the error message it seems the `npm` is trying to install the `node_modules` in a temporary mount point that is no longer available. Try to change the default directory to something more persistent. See here for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19876059/6513921