# NPM still installs global modules into Nodist directory after uninstalling Nodist in Windows

Tags: windows, npm, npm-install, chocolatey, nodist

I've used Nodist in the past to have multiple node versions on my workstation, but I no longer needed it, so I've uninstalled Nodist with chocolatey.

However, whenever I install global packages via `npm i -g packagename`, it still installs it under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist` and I can't get rid of it. The prefix in the npmrc file still points to the correct directory (npm directory under AppData/Roaming).

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix the error by just deleting the `.npmrc` file located in the user's folder (`C:\Users\{username}\.npmrc`). I found that by following [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874582/change-default-global-installation-directory-for-node-js-modules-in-windows) about the `.npmrc` config file.