# How to install puppeteer without using npm?

Tags: puppeteer

I was trying to install puppeteer using `npm -i puppeteer`. But i'm geeting error as i dont have admin rights.
Is there any way to download the package folder and paste it into my project folder?

I downloaded the files from puppeteer GitHub page, but I'm getting errors and there are many folders.
What should be the path?
These doesn't seem to work.
const puppeteer = require('./puppeteer');
const puppeteer = require('./puppeteer/packages/puppeteer');
[Image: Files downloaded from github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chePx.png)(these files are under the folder named puppeteer)

Comment: Why do you need admin rights to run `npm`? Not sure how it is handled on Windows, but maybe you could try installing `npm` again locally (to your user). Otherwise you could try using a minified version of puppeeter, which should include everything bundled into one file. But I strongly disagree doing this. You could also take a look at WSL or ultimately run a virtual machine with an OS with admin privileges

Comment: Why not [NVM](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)?

Comment: I'm using a network computer and it is not allowing me to install. It is trying to install in C:\Windows\node_modules.
I'm getting, Error: EPERM: operation not permitted. SO i was wondering if i could paste the puppeteer folder in my project folder. But when i run it gives me error as " puppeteer\packages\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\puppeteer.js'. Please verify
that the package.json has a valid "main" entry "

Comment: Sounds like it is trying to install globally. Do you have any permissions or ability to save files anywhere else? Maybe a different network share, or local filesystem. You could try changing the global folder for `npm` as [described on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874582/change-default-global-installation-directory-for-node-js-modules-in-windows). There are tons of different answers on that thread alone, let alone the documentation for npm.